# dont show hide post which user had hide that post

Tags: php, mysql

Table Name: user_post

**id**     **user_id**         **post**

1           2                 hi ths is aaaaa

2           3                 hi ths is yyyyyy

3           4                 hi ths is zzzzz

Table Name: hide_post

**id**       **post_id**     **user_id**     **status**

1        1                      2                   hide

And my i had given login userid session as $_SESSION['2'] or any id number which logins

All user can see the All post , If  post 1 is hidden by user_id 2 only he cannot view hidden that post 1.

All member who login can see the post if any member hides the post they cannot view that post.

please give me mysql query and exexute in php

Comment: this question has nothing to do with javascript or jquery. Please don't use irrelevant tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM `user_post`
  WHERE `id` NOT IN (
    SELECT `post_id` FROM `hide_post`
      WHERE `user_id` = '{$userID}'
      AND `status` = 'hide'
  )
```

Here the `{$userID}` should be the current logged in User's ID.

Comment: my table is in different ways.... i had given in basic form, real table is very large... so i was still doing

Comment: Okay now what happened @ShoaibMansuri?

Comment: its repeat the table value

Comment: What exactly is your table structure? Can you show us a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: do you have teamviewer or ammay admin

Comment: i downloaded but... can you say where can i get share password

Comment: did you got it, what happned